# Загадочные возможности

Tags: golang

Почему функция может вернуть ссылку на локальную переменную, и мы будем безнаказанно эту ссылку использовать потом? Заявляется, что локальная переменная будет существовать даже после завершения функции

```
var p = f()
```

Где `f`:

```
func f() int*{
    v:=1
    return &v
}
```

Comment: Это же не си. Здесь есть сборка мусора и анализ локальности. Переменная просто превращается из стековой в хиповую.